# Is there a way to identify a missing log entry through Humio query?

Tags: falcon, humio

I am trying to query a logs from Humio and ensure all the required files are loaded.

If the log entry is not present for a given file then I wanted that result alone.

Eg: My logs have
"Completed Loading FileA"
"Completed Loading FileC"
"Completed Loading FileD"

Query: Using regular expression below I have the all FileName.

**regex("Completed Loading (?.+)")**

FileA, FileB, FileC and FileD are required file. I tried to use all inbuilt functions but the results are not as expected and unable to identify the missing file using the query. The above regex gives me filtered 3 rows in the FileName but I have hard time finding out the missing FileB result. Any suggestion please?